# Why webViewDidStartLoad is not calling?

Tags: ios, swift

Using swift with Xcode8

Below is my view controller.swift

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var XWebview: WKWebView!
    var activity = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.XWebview = WKWebView()
        self.XWebview.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view = self.XWebview
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        XWebview.navigationDelegate = self
        activity.center = self.view.center
        activity.color = UIColor.gray
        XWebview.addSubview(activity)

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let XURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")


        let XURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: XURL! as URL)
        XWebview.load(XURLRequest as URLRequest)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activity.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activity.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

I did not see any indicator when load web view?
Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `WKWebView` and implemented the `UIWebView` delegate. It will not trigger. You have to implement `WKWebView` protocol methods.

Implement the following `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol method to identify start loading the view. This will be triggered when a main frame navigation starts.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

Make sure your activity indicator color with not same as`WKWebView` background color. Make it grey

Use main queue to show/hide activity indicator.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    activity.startAnimating()
 }

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    activity.stopAnimating()
 }
```

Use `grey` color for activity indicator if your web view is white color.

```
var activity = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
```

Comment: bingo hence +1. Or OP can also implement UIWebViewDelegate by confirming to that rather than confirming to WKNavigationDelegate if he is keen on getting the call to webViewDidStartLoad :)

Comment: Thanks. but how to implement the WKWebView protocol methods? Please see my new code above....thanks.

Comment: Use main queue to show/hide the activity indicator.  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            activity.startAnimating()
        }

Comment: Thanks. Now I can call didStartProvisionalNavigation methods. but still not see any indicator.

Comment: Start loader animation before `XWebview.load(XURLRequest as URLRequest)`. And stop it on error and success case

Comment: If your web view is white color then use grey color for activity indicator. var activity = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

Comment: How do I use main queue? How to call it before XWebview.load(XURLRequest as URLRequest)?

Comment: First change the color of your activity indicator and check. I have updated my answers also. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks. I already change the color. and don't know where to put main queue code.

Comment: Add the main queue in `didStartProvisionalNavigation` and `didFinish`. Where you start and stop the animation of your activity indicator

Comment: Really appreciated your time. But still cannot see any indicator. I even comment sopAnimating code.

Comment: Check the activity indictor frame. You are setting `center` . Just print the frame of indicator. then you will come to know what is the location of your indicator

Comment: Add indicator to your `View` not to `WKWebview`

Comment: oh.... my friend. you really save my life. The indicator is on top very left so I didn't notice it. Really really appreciated.

Comment: Move the frame code to view will appear. ` override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        activity.center = self.view.center
        activity.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - (37/2), y: self.view.center.y - (37/2), width: 37, height: 37)
        activity.color = UIColor.gray
        self.view.addSubview(activity)
    }`

Comment: wow..appreciated again. now all working and indicator is in the center of screen. : )